# I have a trigger that makes callout to external system in a future(callout=true) but does not run immediately. Where is this callout queued?

Tags: callout, future

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void makeCallout() {
    System.debug('Hello World-1!');
        
    // Instantiate a new Http object
    Http h = new Http();
    String endpoint = 'https://*******;
    string username = *****; 
    string password = *****;
    Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
    String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);// Base 64 Encode the blob and prepend "Basic "
    String etag = '20240216T183123.996 GMT';
    ApplicationReadWriteMode mode = System.getApplicationReadWriteMode();
            
    // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method as well as the endpoint
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    req.setMethod('PUT');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);// Add the basic auth string to the Request Header           
    req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');// Configure standard headers
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');// Tell API that we are sending and receiving the data as a JSON object
    req.setBody(genPayload('Resolved-Completed'));
        
    //Send the request, and return a response
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    System.debug('response status code ' + res.getStatusCode());
    System.debug(res.getBody());
    System.debug(mode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. Going async (future, batch, schedulable, queueable, platform event) means you're letting Salesforce execute things when they determine they have the resources available to do so.

In practice, you'll typically only need to wait a few seconds or so before the `@future` job will *start* executing. Keep in mind, however, that callouts take a long time (relatively speaking) to execute, and that you won't get an execution log that you can look at until the entire `@future` has completed executing. You'll also be getting a *separate* execution log, because the `@future` method is run in a completely separate "transaction" from the thing that calls it.

`@future` "jobs" get put into the `AsyncApexJob` object, which you can query. Since we don't get a job id for @future calls though, you'd need to get the class Id, the method name, or some similar piece of information to be able to effectively query that object.

From the UI, you should be able to monitor `@future` jobs (as well as batch and queueable jobs) from Setup -> Environments -> Jobs -> Apex Jobs

Comment: and I'm sure that Phil W will be along shortly to give some advice about how calling `@future` from a trigger isn't really good practice.

Comment: How did you guess! It's a pet hate for me... I like properly bulletproof approaches that don't break because you're updating more than 200 records in an already async context (such as a batch). The [usual link](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/). Oh, and [the code example](https://github.com/sirephil/sf-async-callout).